# Handlebars and caching (template not updating)

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I've working with Handlebars for a while now and never had any issues. However recently my development cycle has been disturbed. Handlebars or nodejs for that matter seems to (what I think) cache my templates and refuse to update, even after a server restart.

I tried reading the documentation over at http://handlebarsjs.com but not much is said. As stated I don't really know if this is a Handlebars issue or if it is node.

***How does one debug this kind of issue?***

Comment: Is it express.js? Can you show some code how you define or initialise handlebars?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I was testing in Chrome and found an option to turn off browser caching when f12 tools are up.  You can find it under Settings in f12 tools screen

Answer (score 0):

I too hit this error.

Tested in different browsers, so no way is this a cache issue.

For me, the fix was to restart my node server manually.  For some reason, changes to .hbs files didn't trigger a `nodemon`  restart automatically.

Info posted here to aid others who may hit this bump in the road.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves your problem, but in my case, it was a bug in my code.

I accidentally didn't put "const" or "var" before a variable in an async function. As a result, the variable was accidentally declared in a global scope. Concurrent requests had the wrong value.